# Azure Service Bus Explorer - "Could not contact host in connection string"

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I'm getting this error when trying to connect via Service Bus Explorer. My connection string is perfectly fine and works in my application. What may be wrong?

[image]

Comment: Also raised as a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/issues/459).

Comment: If in case you are looking to connect your Service Bus using connection string to do the message processing, then I would suggest looking into Serverless360 which has all capabilities of Service Bus Explorer and also it will be efficient for production use.